# Get selected file's content before submitting upload form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, patch

I have a form when I am asking the user to upload a `.patch` file along with that few text inputs.

Can I get the contents of that files or more specifically few lines (changed files for the patch) and show it to the user in a maybe in a disabled textbox before he submits the form ?

[image]

Comment: i don´t know if it works with .patch files but you can try this..https://github.com/bgrins/filereader.js

Comment: Why did you tag this question [PHP] ? Do you have to send the file to the server to get the lines you want? I think it would be easier to do it in Javascript

Comment: @anestv My stack is PHP, hence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is read the .patch file and parse it with `RegEx` to get the files names within.

`.patch` file is a text file which has a format like:

```
--- src.orig/java/org/apache/nutch/analysis/NutchAnalysisConstants.java 
+++ src/java/org/apache/nutch/analysis/NutchAnalysisConstants.java
```

so each "--- " indicates a file name, so you can read the content of the file selected and use regex to get the file names and add them to your input:

```
$("#fileInput").on("change", function(){ //When a new file is selected
    var file = $("#fileInput").prop("files")[0]; //get the file

   if (file.name.indexOf(".patch") < 0) {
      alert("You can only select .patch files");
      $("#fileInput").val("");
   }
   else {
       var reader = new FileReader(); 
       reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
       reader.onload = function (evt) {  //When file is loaded.
           $("#text").html("");

           var fileContent = evt.target.result; //event.target.result is the file content
           var names = fileContent.match(/--- .*?\s/g); //Use regex to get lines starting with --- ending with \s

           $(names).each(function(i,e){
                $("#text").html($("#text").html() + e + "\n"); //Add each line to the disabled textarea
                $("#text").attr("rows", ++i); //sets height of textarea to the no. of lines
           });
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Since we are already reading the file... can we add a validation in the onchange to let user only choose .patch files

Comment: If you use `console.log(file);` after taking it from the input, you'll see that it has a `name` property. You can check that `file.name` ends with `.patch`. HTML5 also has a `accept` property on the input but it currently has limited and inconsistent support. But depending on the security level you want for the application and the type of users, they could get an executable and rename it to `.patch`, your client side would pass the validation but would cause problems on the server side. So it's best to validate file type on the server as well.

Comment: I have the validation on the server side in php... Just wanted to add an additional on the input.

Comment: Yeah, OK, like I said there's `<input type="file" accept=".patch"` but doesn't work on all browsers. If you have server side validation as well then add `accept`, check the file extension from `file.name`, and that should be fine. On file change you could check `if (file.name.indexOf(".patch") < 0) { alert('Use .patch file only');}`

Comment: There's been an edit to my answer to add newline, which was my initial code, but the file I tested with already had newlines so I had removed them. Anyway.

Comment: I am having some browser compatibility issues.... Are we missing something... Seems to not work properly in some browsers.